# How to quey apt conf for default apt cache size?

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude, apt-cache

I am required to report the default cache size used by `apt-cache`.
I tried below but there is no result. How can I find out the cache size? Any guidance?

```
$ apt-config dump  | grep -i APT::Cache-Limit
```

Edit -  Following answer from Ravexina
If `Cache-Limit` is preset to zero, which implies `Cache-Limit` to be unlimited. And if, along with it, `Cache-Start` and `Cache-Grow` are too set to some defaults. Then why does not
`apt-config dump` capture this info.   Grepping for below gave no result.

`$apt-config dump | grep -E "Cache-Start|Cache-Grow|Cache-Limit"`
*no result*

Answer (score 3):

```
man apt.conf | less -p 'Cache-Limit'
```

> The default of Cache-Limit is 0 which stands for no limit.